# cut scoping link between key and data.frame for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When using **data.table** as a lookup it is very fast.  There is one behavior that does not work with my current workflow and I'm sure there's a better way and I'm missing it.  The behavior is that of modifying in place even if the key was taken from a parent `data.frame`, **data.table** will act on the parent `data.frame` in ways that may not always be desirable.

Here's an example since I lack the language to express it properly:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
N <- 100

key <- data.frame(x = sample.int(N, N), y = 1:N, z = 1:N)
key$w <- key$x
head(key)
##    x y z  w
## 1 29 1 1 29
## 2 79 2 2 79
## 3 41 3 3 41
## 4 86 4 4 86
## 5 91 5 5 91
## 6  5 6 6  5

set.seed(1)
terms <- data.frame(z = sample.int(2 * N, 1e2, replace = TRUE))
subkey <- key[c("x", "y")]

setDT(subkey)
setDT(terms)

setkey(subkey, x)
subkey[terms][[2]]

head(key)
##   x  y z w
## 1 1 74 1 1
## 2 2 35 2 2
## 3 3 51 3 3
## 4 4 18 4 4
## 5 5  6 5 5
## 6 6 54 6 6
```

Notice the order of `key` is affected by the use of `data.table` even though it wasn't used in the lookup?

I know `data.table` is avoiding making copies but is there a way to cut this link to `key` and force `data.table` to act on `subkey` without modifying `key`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with version 1.9.3. Btw you can always use `copy` to explicitly copy, e.g. `subkey = copy(key[c("x", "y")])`

Comment: @eddi: I'm still seeing this with the GitHub version of `data.table`. **EDIT**: Latest Ubuntu 64-bit

Comment: @edi I'm using windows and `1.9.3` from GitHub produces the same.  Maybe OS specific or you get your version of 1.9.3 elsewhere.

Comment: @MrFlick currently this may be the most appealing solution.

Comment: I have a somewhat older 1.9.3 version on Windows (side Q: is there a way to track github versions that's sequential?) - perhaps smth has changed since then. You should add a bug report.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug but a feature?

Comment: @TylerRinker I don't see this as a feature. What R version do you have?

Comment: The dev version.  That may be the difference.

Comment: This is due to the way R3.1+ handles column subsets. It shallow copies wherever possible. I'd suggest that you first do `setDT(key)` followed by `subkey <- key[, c("x", "y"), with=FALSE]` - column subset in `data.table` deep copies exactly to avoid this issue. There's currently no way to tell how many references are there to a column that's been shallow copied...

Comment: @eddi, we've already noted this down [#710](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/710).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than

```
subkey <- key[c("x", "y")]
setDT(subkey)
```

just do

```
subkey <- as.data.table(key[c("x", "y")])
```

That will force a copy and sever the connection

Comment: I think this is the easiest fix for the work flow. Thank you for the suggestion.